# What spells can be held in a wand?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, magic-items

I know that wands can hold spells of 4th level or lower.

My question is, are only spells listed on page 246 of the DMG able to be placed in wands? Or can you craft a wand with any spell 4th level or lower?

My concern comes in with spells like Power Word Pain, in a wand.

Comment: If it broadly states spells of 4th level or lower, and Power Word Pain is a level 1 spell, then why wouldn't it work?

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein To be fair, 3.5 is definitely an edition that sometimes hides important caveats or qualifications in unexpected places. Just because something in one place seems to allow things doesn’t necessarily mean there isn’t some limitation somewhere else. Sadly.

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein I, too, can imagine a DM's objections to a *wand of power word pain* specifically but instead because of the difficulty of visualizing such *wand*'s effect: The *wand*'s user takes *wand* in hand, points the *wand* at the target, utters the *wand*'s command word *Urgonnabeinaworlduv*, and then… the *wand* says *Pain* at the creature? That *is* weird (albeit not *that* much weirder than *D&D 3.5* magic items are normally).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to craft wands, you need the [Craft Wand](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#craftWand) feat, which says:

> You can create a wand of any 4th-level or lower spell that you know.

So anyone who can craft wands, can craft wands of any 4th-level or lower spell they know.

That would include *power word: pain*. However, note that all item-creation rules are explicitly guidelines, and your DM may nix particular options. Scrolls, wands, and similar are usually fine, but *power word: pain* is a significantly overpowered spell, so it might be one of the few that a DM should object to.

Comment: New house rule, for every wand casting of power word pain by a player, the DM can throw a book at them? ^^